# Toggling actions individually in cards mapped over

Tags: reactjs, button, jsx, toggle, map-function

I have cards that are mapped over They all have a toggle button menu and Im trying to figure out how to target the menu's individually since they are controlled by a single part of the state Im not even sure this is possible. But I think it should be right? I have created a simple  [working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-faraday-tjs8c?file=/src/App.js). Im not sure if I can use the ID of them to target them individually but im not sure how to implement that. Any advice would be helpful thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First of all you can't control all state of `Items` with single boolean state, You can create `open` as an array and then initially set it as `false`.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(Array.from(Items, () => false));
```

**2)** When you want to toggle particular element then you can use `index`

```
onClick={() => toggle(idx)}
```

**3)** Then you have to handle 2 cases where you update `newOpenState`

*case: 1*: when you update respective state after you click on the button. In this case you are just toggling the value which is present at the index `idx`

```
<Button
    isOpen={open[idx]}
    onClick={() => toggle( idx )}
    style={{
        width: "30px",
        height: "30px",
        marginTop: "25px",
        marginLeft: "10px"
    }}
/>
```

*case 2*: When you externally providing the value

```
<Col
    md="12"
    onClick={() => toggle( idx, false )}
    className="editCol"
>
```

So these two cases are covered by using a single expression as:

```
newOpenState[index] = value ?? !newOpenState[index];
```

what above statement means is if the `value` is provided(case 2) then you just have to assign the value to `newOpenState[index]`. If you haven't provided the value(case 1) then it will be `undefined`, and you have to just toggle the value of `newOpenState[index]`. I've used using [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) you can assign the right hand side value of `??` if left hand side of value is `undefined` or `null`.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**CODE**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Card, Button, Col, Row } from "reactstrap";
import { useState } from "react";

const Items = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    ID: 1234
  },
  {
    name: "Test 2",
    ID: 4321
  },
  {
    name: "Test 3",
    ID: 3421
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(Array.from(Items, () => false));

  const toggle = (index, value) => {
    const newOpenState = [...open];
    newOpenState[index] = value ?? !newOpenState[index];
    setOpen(newOpenState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
        {Items.map((item, idx) => (
          <Card
            key={idx}
            style={{
              border: "solid",
              borderColor: "#00000",
              margin: "5px",
              width: "150px",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
            <span style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {!open[idx] ? (
                <Button
                  isOpen={open[idx]}
                  onClick={() => toggle(idx)}
                  style={{
                    width: "30px",
                    height: "30px",
                    marginTop: "25px",
                    marginLeft: "10px"
                  }}
                >
                  ...
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <Card
                  style={{
                    border: "solid 1px",
                    borderColor: "#00000",
                    margin: "5px"
                  }}
                >
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12" className="closeMenu">
                      <span className="X" onClick={() => toggle(idx, false)}>
                        X
                      </span>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col
                      md="12"
                      onClick={() => toggle(idx, false)}
                      className="editCol"
                    >
                      <span
                        className="editName"
                        onClick={() => setOpen(item.ID)}
                      >
                        Edit Name
                      </span>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12">
                      <span
                        className="deleteForm"
                        onClick={() => handleFormDelete(item.ID)}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </span>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Card>
              )}
            </span>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I mostly understand what youre getting at here but I dont understand how youre setting newOpenState in the toggle function. Could you explain?

Comment: I've added the explanation. Hope this is what you want...